# How to disable sortable headers in Admin theme tables

Tags: theming

I'm outputting some data from a custom module as follows

```
theme('table', array('rows' => $rows, 'header' => $headers ));
```

to a custom `/admin` page that will be viewed using the Administrative theme.

Problem is that the headers are generated as (a) clickable and (b) the selected columns have up/down sort arrows. But when you click on the arrows, no sorting happens.

How can I either remove this styling from the header, or implement a sort for the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by reading this fine article

https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/drupal-7-creating-drupal-style-tables-paging-sorting-and-filter

"If you do not want a particular column to be sortable, do not specify the 'field' parameter for its header."

My headers array is now simply

```
   $headers = array(
      array('data' => 'UID'),
      array('data' => 'Username'),
      array('data' => 'Given Name'),
      array('data' => 'Family Name'),
      array('data' => 'Email Address')
    );
```

with no 'field' value specified, and the clickable headers have disappeared.